# Include Button In Form Without Submitting

Tags: jquery, html, forms

How can I place a button inside a form which when clicked will not submit the form?

**Demo HTML:**

```
<form>
    <button>TEST</button>
</form>
<div></div>
```

**Demo JavaScript (jQuery):**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        $('div').append('SUBMITTED<br>');
        return false;
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1r0Lb7dd/)

When the button is clicked the form gets submitted. Is there a way to disable this behavior (rendering this demo form unsubmittable)?

My actual use case for this is creating a bootstrap styled button to activate a file input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default `<button>` `type` is `submit`, so just make it `button`:

```
<form>
    <button type="button">TEST</button>
</form>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1r0Lb7dd/2/)

Comment: Works perfectly. Funny that you have to specify `button` twice rather than `submit` once.

Answer (score 1):

There is the tag `<button>` in HTML.
You could use something like this:

```
<button type="button">This is the button label</button>
```

You can check the definition and usage here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp